# How to calculate Big O of nested for loop

Tags: for-loop, big-o

Im under the impression that to find the big O of a nested for loop, one multuplies the big O of each forloop with the next for loop. Would the big O for:

```
    for i in range(n):
         for j in range(5):
              print(i*j)
```

be O(5n)? and if so would the big O for:

```
 for i in range(12345):
      for j in range(i**i**i)
           for y in range (j*i):
                print(i,j,y)
```

be `O(12345*(i**i**i)*(j*i)`? Or would it be `O(n^3)` because its nested 3 times?
Im so confused

Comment: O(5n) is O(n), so the first one is just O(n). The second example boils down to being just a number, so it's O(1)

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit simplified, but hopefully will get across the meaning of Big-O:

Big-O is about the question "how many times does my code do something?", answering it in algebra, and then asking "which term matters the most in the long run?"

For your first example - the number of times the `print` statement is called is `5n` times. `n` times in the outer loop times `5` times in the inner loop. What matters most in the long run? In the long run only `n` matters, as the value of `5` never changes! So the overall Big-O complexity is `O(n)`.

For your second example - the number of times the print statement is called is very large, but constant. The outer loop runs `12345` times, the inner loop runs one time, then `16` times, then `7625597484987`... all the way up to `12345^12345^12345`. The innermost loop goes up in a similar fashion. What we notice is all of these are constants! The number of times the print statement is called doesn't actually vary *at all*. When an algorithm runs in *constant time*, we represent this as `O(1)`. Conceptually this is similar to the example above - just as `5n / 5 == n`, `12345 / 12345 == 1`.

The two examples you have chosen only involve stripping out the constant factors (which we always do in Big-O, they never change!). Another example would be:

```
def more_terms(n):
  for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
      print(n)
      print(n)
  for k in range(n):
    print(n)
    print(n)
    print(n)
```

For this example, the print statement is called `2n^2 + 3n` times. For the first set of loops, `n` times for the outer loop, `n` times for the inner loop and then `2` times inside the inner lop. For the second set, `n` times for the loop and `3` times each iteration. First we strip out the constants, leaving `n^2 + n`, now what matters in the long run? When `n` is `1`, neither really matter. But the bigger `n` gets, the bigger the difference is, `n^2` grows much faster than `n` - so this function has complexity `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly the answer I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about O(n^3) for your second example. You can calculate big O like this:

Any number of nested loops will add an additional power of 1 to n. So, if we have three nested loops, the big O would be O(n^3). For any number of loops, the big O is O(n^(number of loops)). One loop is just O(n). Any monomial of n, such as O(5n), is just O(n).

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand what O(n) means. It's hard to understand at first, so no shame in not understanding it.
O(n) means "This grows at most as fast as n". It has a rigorous mathematical definition, but it basically boils down to is this.
If f and g are both functions, f=O(g) means that you could pick some constant number C, and on big inputs like n, f(n) < C*g(n)." Big O represents an upper bound, and it doesn't care about constant factors, so if f=O(5n), then f=O(n).

Comment: This doesn't answer the second example.